# Blazor and OIDC iframes Content Security Policy error

Tags: authentication, http-headers, blazor, identityserver4, openid-connect

I had implemented OIDC authentication in my Blazor WebAssembly app (v6.0.6, non-hosted with ASP.NET), which worked fine. I had used Microsoft's template for new Blazor WebAssembly app with Authentication Type "Individual Accounts". My extra code :

**Program.cs**

```
...

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
{ 
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["httpClientBaseAddress"]) 
});

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
});

...
```

**appsetting.json**

```
{
   "oidc": {
    "Authority": "https://xxx.xxx.xx",
    "ClientId": "clientIdxxx",
    "DefaultScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "email", "xxapi" ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "authentication/logout-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

The Identity Server 4 we are using for central authentication is set for accepting my app.

All worked fine! However, after updating in version v6.0.7, I get the following error and my app never redirects to 'https://xxx.xxx.xx' for providing my credentials:

> Refused to frame 'https://xxx.xxx.xx' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

No changes have made in Identity server, so I assume it is fault of the update.

So, having in mind that I'm using a Blazor WASM standalone app, how can I add the right headers for the 'Content Security Policy'?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's that http client for? Please take a look at this doc on how to use those. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: IdentityServer4 had a file on its sample code called "SecurityHeaders" that adds a quite restrictive CSP header to any IdentityServer4 view, which prevents them from being embedded.

Comment: Yes, I have in mind to refactor http client according to the article you mentioned. As for IdentityServer's "SecurityHeaders", I found it. Does it have to change? But how did my app work before and then it didn't?

Comment: probably is a change in how your browser version respect that headers, not their presence.

Comment: I mean what you need to do is understand what the CSP string that file adds to your views means and what should be the result according to the specification. If you were experiencing something different, and that file hasn't changed, it's the browser that has changed.

Comment: Exactly same error here after updating to v6.0.7.  Any clue?